# .htaccess - remove parameters from URL only on homepage

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using parameters on some subpages, but google index them in the search results for some reason in the homepage URL.

How can I please remove them in `.htaccess` only for homepage?

remove `?a=123` here:

- `example.com/?a=123` (result: `example.com`)

don't remove it here:

- `example.com/subpage/event.php?a=123`

I found this, but I don't know how to apply it only for homepage:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule (.*) $1?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```sh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^/?$ / [R=301,L,QSD]
```

- `%{QUERY_STRING} .` means "query string contains at least one character"
- `^/?$` is "just the home page" -- ie the URL path only consists of an optional slash
- `[R=301]` Redirects the request (to change the URL)
- `[L]` is the last rewrite rule so that it doesn't conflict with later ones
- `[QSD]` is "query string delete" so that rewrite doesn't try to append the query string to the redirect